# ReactJS - How to generate social meta tags before page render?

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags

I am having an issue loading social meta tags generated from my JS file when sharing via sms.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(decObject)) {
 if (key === "title" || key === "description" || key === "image" || key === "url") {
  var meta_og = document.createElement('meta');
  var meta_twt = document.createElement('meta');
  meta_og.setAttribute('property', `og:${key}`);
  meta_twt.setAttribute('property', `twitter:${key}`);
  meta_og.content = value;
  meta_twt.content = value;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta_og);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta_twt);
 }
}
```

With the code above, I parse out the keys and values from my object and use them as my meta property and content. When I run this, it displays in the HTML section on the inspect element but when I share the link after uploading it to my server, the social meta tags don't appear. I tried implementing the meta tags physically inside the index.html file and they work when sharing. I tried using "react-helmet", and other packages but they are not working for me. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should consider to use something like [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) to update meta data dynamically.

Comment: So you're saying run helmet in my Node backend? I tried using express-mustache to pull the meta tags but it didn't work for me. Maybe I was doing it incorrectly but not sure.

Comment: Helmet can be used client side. Or server side if your using SSR.